# Trouble writing an APEX Test class

Tags: apex

New to APEX, so I'm having a bit of trouble with the logic of how to create this test class. In the trigger, upon insertion of a Note, I track down the Note's Account's Owner's Email Address and send it an email.

I'll put the trigger code first:

```
trigger FireNoteEmailTrigger on Note (after insert) {
    //grab ID of the note
    Note note = trigger.new[0];
    //find account that has that note ID
    Account foundAccount = note.Parent;
    String emailTitle = note.Title;
    //find owner ID of that account id
    User foundOwner = foundAccount.Owner;
    //find email of that owner ID
    String ownerEmail = foundOwner.Email;
    //send email notification to ownerEmail using emailTitle as title
    EmailMessage e = new EmailMessage();
    e.Status = '5'; 
    e.TextBody = emailTitle;
    e.Subject = emailTitle;
    e.ToAddress = ownerEmail;
    insert e;
    List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> 
        results = Messaging.sendEmailMessage(new ID[] { e.id });
    System.assertEquals(1, results.size());
    System.assertEquals(true, results[0].success);
}
```

Here's the test class:

```
@isTest
private class FireNoteEmailTriggerTestClass {
    static testMethod void validateFireNoteEmailTrigger() {
        Note n = new Note();
        insert n;        
        Account a = new Account();
        insert a;
        User u = new User();       
        insert u; 

        //make sure the Account of the Note parent is the same as an Account owned by the User 
        //acc = [SELECT Id FROM a WHERE Owner = Note.Parent.Account]
       // System.assertEquals(u.Id, acc.Id);
    }
}
```

I *think* I'm on the right track with the logic but I'm not sure. Any help?

Comment: You will need to set object attributes such as the Note ParentId to relate the various objects together in your test. At some point you should also bulkify your trigger. (Google how to do that.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a lot of problems with your trigger. Let's address a few of them.

### Assert In Live Code

Unless you want to cause really *ugly* errors, don't assert in live code. Ever. It should only ever be placed in unit tests.

### Bulkify Code

You should be able to handle up to 200 records at once. Simply add each outgoing email to a list, and send them all at once at the end.

### Polymorphic Relationships

You can't cast Parent to an Account, because if it's *not* an Account, your code will crash. This means that notes on contacts, cases, opportunities, custom objects, etc will all fail.

### Obtaining Related Record Data

Triggers don't automatically include relationship data. That means that note.ParentId will be an ID, but note.Parent will be *null.* You have to first query the related record in order to know things like the owner's ID or their email.

### Sending By Email Address Instead Of User ID

Emails sent by email address count towards the 1,000 emails per day limit. You could easily burn through this in mere seconds if there were some mass loading of records. Instead, use SingleEmailMessage.setTargetObjectId to specify the user ID to send to. This will bypass the 1,000 emails per day limit.

### Assigning Temporary Variables Unnecessarily

Sometimes we need variables (all but the most simple code). However, you shouldn't be creating variables for the sake of creating variables. This makes your code harder to maintain as your code base grows.

---

So, having addressed all this, we can then proceed to the core question: how to you unit test this code?

Simply, you need to associate the note to the account, and insert it. Your unit test should look something like this:

```
// Remember all required fields need to be here
Account a = new Account(Name='Test'); 
insert a;
// Attach the note to its parent
Note n = new Note(ParentId=a.Id, Title='Test Title', Body='Test Body');
insert n;
// Make sure an email was sent:
System.assertEquals(1, Limits.getEmailInvocations());
```

Now, as far as actually fixing your trigger, it can be as simple as:

```
trigger sendEmail on Note (after insert) {
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[0];
    Set<Id> parentIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Note record: Trigger.new) {
        parentIds.add(record.parentId);
    }
    Map<Id, Account> accounts = new Map<Id, Account>(
        [SELECT OwnerId FROM Account WHERE Id IN :parentIds]
    );
    for(Note record: Trigger.new) {
        Account thisAccount = accounts.get(record.ParentId);
        if(thisAccount != null) {
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            message.setSubject(record.Title);
            message.setPlainTextBody(record.Body);
            message.setTargetObjectId(thisAccount.OwnerId);
            // Required to Email users
            message.setSaveAsActivity(false);
            messages.add(message);
        }
    }
    if(!messages.isEmpty()) {
        Messaging.sendEmail(messages);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Small tweak to sfdcfox's trigger in pursuit of my obsession with avoiding queries in standard object triggers as standard objects are used for many purposes in an org.

Many thousands of Notes might be added every day to other standard objects such as Contact or to custom objects in various apps for every Note added to an Account. So to avoid an unnecessary query on Account for those cases:

```
trigger sendEmail on Note (after insert) {
    Set<Id> parentIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Note record: Trigger.new) {
        if (record.parentId.getSObjectType() == Account.SObjectType) {
            parentIds.add(record.parentId);
        }
    }
    if (!parentIds.isEmpty()) {
        Map<Id, Account> accounts ...
    }
}
```